# Проблема с GET И SET в JavaScript при увеличении регистра букв

Tags: javascript, массивы, get, словари, set

Всем привет, что надо переделать в коде что увеличивались буквы все, и выводились все, вот мой код

```js
let zo = {
  s: "zen",
  x: "fuz",
  get full() {
    return `${this.s} ${this.x}`;
  },
  set full(v) {
    [this.s, this.x] = v.toUpperCase();
  }
};
zo.full = "red fiz";
console.log(zo.full);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Значением параметра `v` в данном случае является присваиваемая строка `"red fiz"`.

В сеттере идет попытка разобрать эту строку как массив и сохранить первые два элемента массива в соответствующие свойства.

По сути запись

```
[this.s, this.x] = v.toUpperCase();
```

эквивалентна

```
var upper = v.toUpperCase();
this.s = upper[0];
this.x = upper[1];
```

Таким образом видно, что в случае со строкой просто возьмутся первые две буквы.

Для решения достаточно преобразовать передаваемую строку в массив, например с помощью метода [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

```js
let zo = {
  s: "zen",
  x: "fuz",
  get full() {
    return `${this.s} ${this.x}`;
  },
  set full(v) {
    [this.s, this.x] = v.toUpperCase().split(' ');
  }
};
zo.full = "red fiz";
console.log(zo.full);
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
let zo = {
  s: "zen",
  x: "fuz",
  get full() {
    return `${this.s} ${this.x}`;
  },
  set full(v) {
    [this.s, this.x] = v.toUpperCase().split(' ');
  }
};
zo.full = "red fiz";
console.log(zo.full);
```